# Where should werkzeug be located for local dev using Flask with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, werkzeug

I've installed in in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ which is added to the  Python path via .bash_profile

When I attempt to run GAE  dev_appserver.py I keep getting:

ImportError: No module names werkzeug.exceptions

When I print the sys.path from within the GAE flask demo, /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/  does not show up on the Python path.

Where should the werkzeug package be installed to develop GAE on my local machine?  The GAE Flask tutorial omits this info.

Answer (score 2):

I put mine in a separate `libs` directory for the project, and deploy it with the project

```
default
  - application
  - libs
    - flask
    - werkzeug
    - etc
  app.yaml
```

Then, in `application.__init__.py`, I put:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

from flask import Flask

etc.....
```